# How to use varchar minus sign for mathematical operation in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I am trying to convert local time value to UTC value using a UTC offset value that is in a `varchar(6)` format. For example, "+03:30" or "-05:00" or "+08:00".

I have the following SQL statement to calculate the UTC based on the UTC offset.

```
    DECLARE @d datetime = '2014-08-01 02:55:00.000'
    DECLARE @off varchar(6) =  '+00:05'

    select 
        left(@off,1) as '+/-',
        (convert(int, SUBSTRING(@off,2,2)*60)) as 'hh',
        (convert(int, RIGHT(@off,2))) as 'mm',
        (convert(int, SUBSTRING(@off,2,2)*60))+ (convert(int, RIGHT(@off,2)))as 'offset',
        @d as 'Local DateTime',
        (SELECT DATEADD(mi,  left(@off,1)+(convert(int, SUBSTRING(@off,2,2)*60) + convert(int,RIGHT(@off,2))), @d)) as 'UTC-calc',
        (SELECT DATEADD(mi,  -5, @d)) as 'UTC-manual'
    from
        mytable
```

Results:

```
    +/- | hh | mm | offset   | Local DateTime            | UTC-calc                  | UTC-manual
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    +   | 0  | 5  | 5        | 2014-08-01 02:55:00.000   |  2014-08-01 03:00:00.000  | 2014-08-01 02:50:00.000
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The script performs as expected when I supply a positive UTC offset value (e.g. '+00:05'). However, if I test a negative value '-00:05', the minutes are not subtracted but added and the results remain the same with the exception of the "+/-" column.

```
    +/- | hh | mm | offset   | Local DateTime            | UTC-calc                  | UTC-manual
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -   | 0  | 5  | 5        | 2014-08-01 02:55:00.000   |  2014-08-01 03:00:00.000  | 2014-08-01 02:50:00.000
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What do I need to do with the minus sign in order to be recognized by SQL as a mathematical operator instead of being treated as a varchar?

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you do not need nested `select` for what you are doing.  So:

```
SELECT (SELECT DATEADD(mi, left(@off,1)+(convert(int, SUBSTRING(@off,2,2)*60) + convert(int,RIGHT(@off,2))), @d)) as 'UTC-calc',
```

is the same as:

```
SELECT DATEADD(mi, left(@off,1)+(convert(int, SUBSTRING(@off,2,2)*60) + convert(int,RIGHT(@off,2))), @d)) as [UTC-calc],
```

The problem is that the string `+` or `-` converts to `0` in an integer context.  And, that is the context for this addition.  Instead, use arithmetic:

```
SELECT DATEADD(mi,
               (case when left(@off, 1) = '-' then -1 else 1 end) *
                (convert(int, SUBSTRING(@off,2,2)*60) + convert(int,RIGHT(@off,2))),
               @d)) as [UTC-calc],
```

That is, use multiplication to make the value negative.

By the way, I'm not so sure you have to go through all this trouble.  SQL Server can convert date/times with timezone information.

Comment: thanks you for the explanation. I tried to use ToDateTimeOffset but SELECT ToDateTimeOffset(@d, @off) returns 2014-08-01 02:55:00.000 -00:05. I need the actual offset time returned. So the desired value to be returned is 2014-08-01 02:50:00.000.